# How to add my images from a folder to my array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

Hi I'm creating a site with my family's holiday images and I have multiple folders with images with each folder for each day, so when the person viewing the site clicks on a folder on the so called 'folders page' he's taken to a page where he can see all images for that day.

So I'm trying to create a array of all the images of each day, but I don't want to hard code it, so I should just be able to add a new image to the folder and it will automatically add it to that days page.

I'm trying to use some sort of counter variable that will count how many images I have in each folder and it will push it to the corresponding array for example when I'm adding to folder called 'day1' it will push that image to the array called 'day1'.

my code for to where I want to push the images looks something like this:

```
const myImages = {
    day1: [
        {
            name: 'my first image',
            src: 'day1/image1.jpg',
            alt: 'First image'
        },
        {
            name: 'my second image',
            src: 'day1/image2.jpg',
            alt: 'Second image'
        }
    ],
    day2: [
        {
            name: 'my third image',
            src: 'day2/image1.jpg',
            alt: 'Third image'
        }
    ]
};
```

I want to have something that should do this:

```
const myImages = {
    day1: [
        {
            name: 'push here from folder day1 the name of image1.jpg',
            src: 'push here from folder day1 the src of image1.jpg',
            alt: 'push here from folder day1 the alt of image1.jpg'
        },
        {
            name: 'push here from folder day1 the name of image2.jpg',
            src: 'push here from folder day1 the src of image2.jpg',
            alt: 'push here from folder day1 the alt of image2.jpg'
        }
    ],
    day2: [
        {
            name: 'push here from folder day2 the name of image1.jpg',
            src: 'push here from folder day2 the src of image1.jpg',
            alt: 'push here from folder day2 the alt of image1.jpg'
        }
    ]
};
```

The way it looks now is:

```
const images = {
    Day_1: [],
    Day_2: [],
    Day_3: [],
    Day_4: [],
    Day_5: [],
    Day_6: [],
    Day_7: [],
    Day_8: [],
    Day_9: [],
    Day_10: [],
    Day_11: [],
    Day_12: []
};
for (let i = 0; i <= 537; i++) {
    if (i <= 28) {
        images.Day_1.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 62) {
        images.Day_2.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 78) {
        images.Day_3.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 114) {
        images.Day_4.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 164) {
        images.Day_5.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 228) {
        images.Day_6.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 313) {
        images.Day_7.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 316) {
        images.Day_8.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 400) {
        images.Day_9.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 451) {
        images.Day_10.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 527) {
        images.Day_11.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    } else if (i <= 537) {
        images.Day_12.push('image_'+i+'.jpg');
    }
}
```

And I hope you understand I can't add my folders from my pc on stackoverflow

Comment: Assuming the best intent here @Shmiel StackOverflow is not a place to ask someone else to build code for you. It's a place for you to share your code and ask for help with it. Since you haven't share code that is trying to solve your problem I'm trying to make you aware of that. Use the edit function under your question to add your code and ask questions about it and we will be glad to help.

Comment: ok, that for loop was pretty rigid.. but if it's nodejs you're using here's an example of what you can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming that it's nodejs being used(because you said a site that shares images from *folders* on YOUR COMPUTER).. we can make that loop way smaller and less rigid

Not sure if this will work for you(since I can't know that much about YOUR computer and how you're setting this up) but I think this is the idea :D

**EDIT**: I have an example on [replit](https://replit.com/@PaulTaylor2/images)

```js
var fs=require('fs') //needed module for reading files
function getImages(rootDirectory){
  let slash=process.platform=="win32"?"\\":"/" //different slash for folder logic in different operating systems
  let isFolder=(path)=>fs.lstatSync(path).isDirectory() //checks if something is a folder or not
  
  var folders=fs.readdirSync(rootDirectory)
  .filter(name=> isFolder(rootDirectory+slash+name) ) //only the folders remain
  var myImages={} //object that will be structured dynamically
  folders.forEach(folderName=>{
    var folder=[] //individual folder(like day1)
    fs.readdirSync(rootDirectory+slash+folderName)
    .filter(fileName=>{ //only files which are images(like ".img")
      let imageArr=['jpg','png','gif'] //image suffixes
      let suffix=fileName.split('.')[1]
      let condition=suffix? imageArr.includes(suffix.toLowerCase()): false //if a file is an image(from the name at leasts)
      return !isFolder(rootDirectory+slash+folderName+slash+fileName) && condition
    })
    .forEach(imageName=>{
      let src=folderName+slash+imageName
      folder.push({src,data:fs.readFileSync(rootDirectory+slash+src)})
      //now I really don't know how you're getting "name" and "alt".. maybe you could have a hash mapping of those stuff I guess
    })
    myImages[folderName]=folder //places a folder(like day1) into the "myImages" object
  })
  return myImages
}

//usage
const myImages=getImages(__dirname) //__dirname is the directory of where the program is running
```

Just to repeat it's a proof of concept of how not to have rigid code like that for loop u got there(yes ik my code is probably pretty scrappy ;-;)